# How do I bind a listview to my very nested object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, win-universal-app

I have a problem with binding my ListView DataTemplate to an observablecollection that has a very nested property.
I've tried to bind using `{Binding Trip.LegList.Leg.name}` but that doesn't work. What is the easiest way to bind something like this?

`_currentTripData` is an `ObservableCollection` of type `Trip`.

```
<ListView Name="ui_tripview_triplist"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding _currentTripData}">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock>
                       <Run Text="{Binding Trip.LegList.Leg.name}" />
                   </TextBlock>

               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
        </ListView>
```

That's how I tried to bind it in first place, but did not work. This is the classes I am using (converted from JSON).

```
public class Leg
{
    public Origin Origin { get; set; }
    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
    public Stops Stops { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class LegList
{
    public List<Leg> Leg { get; set; }
}


public class Trip
{
    public List<ServiceDay> ServiceDays { get; set; }
    public LegList LegList { get; set; }
}
```

It is kind of messy, but that is the objects I've been given to use...

Comment: Because `LegList.Leg.name` dont exits. `Leg` is a `List<Leg>`, not a `Leg`, so dont have `name` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues:

1) You are binding to an **ObservableCollection** of Trips, so you don't need to reference the **Trip** in the binding. You are already in a context of a Trip for each item.

2) LegList.Leg is a **List** which does not have a name property.  You can add a nested ListView and bind the ItemSource to LegList.Leg (ie. `{Binding LegList.Leg}`).  Then bind to the **name** of each **Leg**.

```
<ListView Name="ui_tripview_triplist"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding _currentTripData}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LegList.Leg}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding name}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
</ListView>
```

Comment: This does give me a list, but the name binding still doesn't work, it seems like it can't find the name even though it is in the list when debugging.

Comment: Can you try `<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />` in the nested ListView

Comment: Tovbin's anwer is right, but there is a little mistake. The second `ListView` has not added `<ListView.ItemTemplate>`. After you add it, it runs well.

Comment: Thanks Jayden, a copy/paste error.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

LegList is a list, so binding to Trip.LegList.Leg.name can't work. For example working would be Trip.LegList.Leg[0].name in your case. But I assume that is not what you want.

What I think you want to do is:
Set the ItemsSource of your ListView to _currentTripData.LegList and the Binding to the Run to Text={Binding name}

Comment: Setting the ItemSource to _currentTripData.LegList does not work because it still wants me to use index to choose which leg.... So I have to write _currentTripData[0].LegList.. But my purpose is to list all buses in a ListView so binding to one LegList does not do it for me... I am very stuck on this and I have been trying to figure it out for three days straight...  I am in a hard patch right now haha.

Comment: How about _currentTripData.SelectMany(d => d.LegList) to get a flat list of your data?